# Losing non-url state params after page refresh

Tags: angularjs

```
.state('child', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/child.html',
        controller: 'childCtrl',
        params: {
            'A': null,
        },

    }),
```

Value of `A` getting null after page refresh, if I mention `A` in URL, then it works fine. But I want my URL without `A`.

Comment: No, it is to set the default value

Comment: So how do you expect the browser will know that value after refresh exactly? Set it as a parameter in the URL or change the default value from null the the one you want

Comment: I want the value which I am sending from previous state, it loads the first time but not after refresh